# Sublime Text 2 - Package Control errors

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext

When trying to use package control in SL2, I get the following console errors returned. I've tried looking around, and short of reinstalling not sure what step to take.

'''

```
Exception in thread Thread-6:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 801, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "./package_control/commands/install_package_command.py", line 45, in run
  File "./package_control/package_installer.py", line 58, in make_package_list
  File "./package_control/package_manager.py", line 694, in list_available_packages
  File "./package_control/package_manager.py", line 554, in _list_available
  File "./package_control/package_manager.py", line 453, in list_repositories
  File "./package_control/providers/channel_provider.py", line 201, in get_repositories
  File "./package_control/providers/channel_provider.py", line 87, in fetch
  File "./package_control/download_manager.py", line 340, in fetch
  File "./package_control/downloaders/urllib_downloader.py", line 117, in download
  File "./package_control/downloaders/urllib_downloader.py", line 317, in setup_opener
  File "./package_control/ca_certs.py", line 31, in get_ca_bundle_path
  File "./package_control/ca_certs.py", line 166, in get_system_ca_bundle_path
  File "./package_control/deps/oscrypto/trust_list.py", line 122, in get_path
  File "./package_control/deps/oscrypto/_osx/trust_list.py", line 49, in extract_from_system
  File "./package_control/deps/oscrypto/_ffi.py", line 121, in new
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/cffi/api.py", line 262, in new
    cdecl = self._typeof(cdecl)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/cffi/api.py", line 182, in _typeof
    result = self._typeof_locked(cdecl)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/cffi/api.py", line 167, in _typeof_locked
    type = self._parser.parse_type(cdecl)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/cffi/cparser.py", line 508, in parse_type
    return self.parse_type_and_quals(cdecl)[0]
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/cffi/cparser.py", line 511, in parse_type_and_quals
    ast, macros = self._parse('void __dummy(\n%s\n);' % cdecl)[:2]
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/cffi/cparser.py", line 296, in _parse
    self.convert_pycparser_error(e, csource)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/cffi/cparser.py", line 325, in convert_pycparser_error
    raise CDefError(msg)
CDefError: cannot parse "CFArrayRef *"
<cdef source string>:2:12: before: *
```

'''

Comment: Running on a Mac by any chance?

Comment: Sublime 2 is no longer supported; on MacOS it requires a system installed version of Python, and in newer versions of MacoS the version has changed and as such it will no longer work.